# How does 'percentage contribution' affect rep on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

If person A creates a Q or A, then person B comes in and changes it, the percent contributed will be displayed next to the original posters name.

How does that affect rep?  And is there a certain level where the original poster would no longer accumulate rep for votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't, other than that after 6 edits a post becomes communitiy wiki and no longer accumulates rep.

Answer (score 8):

Percentage is only shown on community wiki posts, which by definition don't generate any rep.

Comment: I didn't realize it was only on wiki posts.  thx +1